# Test sslv3 poodle locally in windows

Tags: openssl

I want to check locally whether my webpage has any sslv3 poodle vulnerabilities. How do check this?

`openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 -ssl3` command works with Linux. On Windows, how do I do this?

Comment: You could run the same command from Linux to your Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [Scan for POODLE using nmap from a Windows machine](https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/scan-for-poodle-using-nmap-from-a-windows-machine)

```
nmap.exe -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers -oN poodle_443 facebook.com
```